# How to SELECT three data results based on comparission of one data item between two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to databases;

I am trying to query (SELECT) ***naam***, ***functie*** and ***schaal*** (salary-scale) of an employee.

But there is a catch, because naam and functie are within the table: "werknemer" and scale is in the table "s_schaal".

[**Here is an image of the ERD:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvMiW.png)

What I think needs to happen is the following:
The employees salary should be looked at and then compared to "***ondergrens***" and "***bovengrens***", if employees salary is equal to or between one of the entries then the correlating "schaal" should be outputted as well.

In order to SELECT wnaam, functie, schaal (corrrelating scale which is in another table).

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT werknemer.wnaam, werknemer.functie, s_schaal.schaal WHERE werknemer.salaris IS >= s_schaal.ondergrens AND werknemer.salaris IS <= s_schaal.bovengrens
```

**This is the error message**

> INSERT INTO werknemer  SELECT * FROM s_schaal  WHERE werknemer.salaris
>   = s_schaal.ondergrens AND werknemer.salaris = s_schaal.bovengrens Error Code: 1054. Unknown column
>   'werknemer.salaris' in 'where clause' 0.000 sec

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a left [outer] join to do that, as in:

```
select w.wnaam, w.functie, s.schaal
from werknemer w
left join s_schaal s 
  on w.salaris >= s.ondergrens and w.salaris <= s.bovengrens
```